# When I transform a selection in gimp, it disappears

Tags: gimp

whenever I transform a selection it disappears becoming a floating selection which I cannot see and when i try to link it to a layer it just disappears from the layers tab and nothing happens.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  This is difficult to answer without seeing anything. Would you mind showing a screenshot, or perhaps an example of what you are trying to achieve.  If you have a floating selection, you can promote it to a layer by hitting the New Layer icon in the layers panel.

Comment: okay here are some screenshots. https://imgur.com/a/ujeqRuT

Comment: first image is what I want, second is me using the rotate tool, third is the floating selection which is invisible and it disappears from the menu after using the anchor layer tool.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. What version of GIMP are you using?  See [This example](https://imgur.com/a/jppR3so) using the latest version 2.10.22

Comment: **I can replicate the problem.** In my case, I'm on GIMP 2.10.28 compiled from source on Gentoo. As @fortnitegamer experiences, *all* floating selections are invisible and thus unusable. Since only a slim minority of us appear to be experiencing this, it's hard to know where to go next with this one. `</sigh>`

Answer (score 0):

Floating selection are a thing in GIMP that can be puzzling - since the pixels have "changed place" from where they were, they are put in this "intermediate" state that is the floating layer.

Basically you have two actions to take to continue editing: eithre anchor back your floating selection on the image, or promote it to a new layer. Both actions are asily reachable as buttons on the Layers dialog.

If you intend to continue transforming or applying filters to the selected area, just promote it to a new layer - then just having that as the active layer will have that area selected. If you anchor it it is "melted" back on the source layer, and you'd have to re-select the same pixels.

As you mention that you are not "seeing" it, it might be the result of your transform ending up outside of the Canvas area, or having an empty-pixel selection to start with. Zooming out might show you the "marching ants" of the resulting selection. Creating a new Layer (first button on Layers selection), and using the `Image->Canvas Size`  option to enlarge the canvas so that the new layer is inside the image may fix the issue for you.